# help with $\;(x+3)^{1/3} = (x-1)^{1/2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, radicals

Taking the 6th power of both sides leads to 
$x^2 + 6x + 9 = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x -1 \;\Rightarrow\;
0 = (x-5)(x^2 + x + 2).$ 
Therefore, the only possible solutions are 
$\;\{5, \frac{-1}{2} \pm i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2} \}.$

$x=5\;$ can be manually verified as satisfying the equation in this posting's title, **but what is the easiest way to determine whether either or both of the other two candidate solutions also satisfy the equation?**

Can this be done without having to solve a cubic equation to determine (for example) all 3 cube roots of $\; \left(\frac{5}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)?$

Furthermore, assume that all 3 cube roots of $\;\left(\frac{5}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\;$ are identified and that both square roots of $\;\left(\frac{-3}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}\right)\;$ are identified.  In order to *conclude* that the equation in the title is satisfied, which of the 3 cube roots are you supposed to compare to which of the two square roots?  Re-wording this last question, when $\;(x+3)\;$ and/or $\;(x-1)\;$ are complex, with at least one of the complex values having *distinct roots*, does this **automatically render the equation ambiguous?**

**My Answer:**

The interface won't allow me to *post an answer,* so I'm placing my conclusion 
here.

Construing $\;e^{i\theta}$ as $\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta),\;$ and using 
de Moivre's theorem, which is easily proven by induction,
$\;\left(e^{i\theta}\right)^n = e^{n\times i\theta}.\;$

Therefore, for $\;n\in\mathbb{Z+},\;$ the equation $\;z^n = 1\;$ will have the n
distinct roots $\xi_k = e^{i\times 2k\pi/n} \;: \;k \in \{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}.$

Further, any fixed **non-zero** complex $z_1$ can be expressed in the form
$\;re^{i\theta},\;$ where $\;0<r\in\mathbb{R},\;$ and $\;\theta\in[0,2\pi).$

Thus, the equation $\;z^n - z_1 = 0,\;$ which can have at most n roots will have
the root $\;z_2 = r^{1/n}e^{i(\theta/n)}.\;$  Therefore the equation $\;z^n - z_1 = 0,\;$
**will always have exactly n distinct roots,** given by $\;z_2\xi_k, \;:
\;k \in \{0,1,\cdots,n-1\}.$

In real analysis, $5$ is considered to be an answer to the equation 
$\;(x+3)^{1/3} = (x-1)^{1/2}\;$  **However,** in complex analysis, 
8 has 3 cube roots, while 4 has 2 square roots, and exactly one of the 3
cube roots coincides with one of the two square roots.

Therefore, in complex analysis, it seems reasonable to **construe** 
$\;[f(z)]^{1/n} = [g(z)]^{1/m}\;:$ $\;f(z),g(z)$ are two polynomials with integer
coefficients and $\;n,m \in \mathbb{Z^+}\;$ 
as **intending** that 
$z_1$ is a solution if and only if at least one of the $n^{th}$ roots of $f(z_1)$
coincides with one of the $m^{th}$ roots of $g(z_1).$

Let $\;z_1 = \frac{-1}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}.\;$
From the analysis shown at the start of this question, 
$\;(z_1 + 3)^2 = (z_1 - 1)^3.\;$
Therefore, the six roots of $\;\{(z_1 + 3)^2\}^{1/6}\;$ exactly coincide with 
the six roots of $\;\{(z_1 - 1)^3\}^{1/6},\;$ and the arguments (i.e. angles) of
these 6 roots will **differ with 
each other by** $(2\pi/6).\;$  Further, 3 of these 6 roots 
correspond to the 3 roots of $\;(z_1 + 3)^{1/3}\;$ and these 3 roots 
will have arguments that **differ with each other by** $(2\pi/3).\;$

Similarly, 2 of these 6
roots correspond to the 2 roots of $\;(z_1 - 1)^{1/2}\;$
and these 2 roots 
have arguments that **differ with each other by** $(2\pi/2).\;$

Therefore, one of the cube roots of $\;(z_1 + 3)\;$ **must coincide** with one
of the square roots of $\;(z_1 - 1).\;$

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to consider the complex solutions?

Comment: @JoelPereira Actually, I found the problem on a foreign language youtube, where I followed the math but couldn't understand what the teacher was saying.  My impression is that the *intent* was to **not** consider complex solutions.  However, I am **regarding** the intent as **irrelevant.**  I intend that my question **does** focus on complex solutions.  I understand that if $\;(z_1)^n = z_2,\;$ then so does $\;(z_1\epsilon)^n,\;$ where $\epsilon$ is **any** of the n roots of unity.  What I am asking is **how do professional mathematicians untangle this mess?**

Comment: The question cannot be answered if you don't specify precisely what is meant by $z^{1/2}$ and $z^{1/3}$ in the complex. (Please don't answer *square and cubic roots*.)

Comment: @YvesDaoust agreed, but in the *answer* that I posted at the end of my question, I offer what I regard as a reasonable **construance** which resolves your issue.

Comment: This information belongs to the question, we shouldn't have to dig the answer.

Comment: @Yves I agree, my thoughts and formulation were haphazard.  Consider that I posted the question one day and then (after percolating about it) *answered it* the next day.  Anyway, for any fixed non-zero complex $\;z_1,\;(z_1)^{1/n}\;$ refers **ambiguously to any of the n solutions to the equation** $\;z^n - z_1 = 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find all $x\in{\mathbb C}$ such that the set
$$(x+3)^{1/3}\cap (x-1)^{1/2}\subset{\mathbb C}$$
is nonempty. In other words, you want to find all $x\in{\mathbb C}$ such that there is an $u\in{\mathbb C}$ with
$$u^3=x+3,\qquad u^2=x-1\ .\tag{1}$$
You already have established that necessarily $$x\in\left\{5,-{1\over2}+i{\sqrt{7}\over2}, -{1\over2}-i{\sqrt{7}\over2}\right\}\ .\tag{2}$$ Now $(1)$ implies that, given $x$, the value of $u$ is determined by
$$u={u^3\over u^2}={x+3\over x-1}\ .\tag{3}$$
The procedure is then clear: For each $x$ in the candidate list $(2)$ compute the corresponding $u$ by means of $(3)$; then check whether  $u^2=x-1$. (This will automatically guarantee $u^3=x+3$ as well.) The candidates $x$ that pass this test can be considered as solutions to the original equation under the chosen interpretation.

Comment: nice elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $5$ is a solution.

$\left|\frac{5}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}\right|^{\frac 13}$ and $\left|\frac{-3}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}\right|^{\frac 12}$ are respectively $(\sqrt 8)^{\frac 13}$ and $2^\frac 12,$ so they are equal.
Thus the three cube roots of $\;\color{red}{a=\frac{5}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}}\;$ and the two square roots of $\;\color{blue}{b=\frac{-3}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}}\;$ are located on the same $\color{violet}{\text{circle}}$ centered in $O,$ with radius $\sqrt 2.$

Due to the relative position of cube/square roots of a complex number, there can be at most one common root. The picture [drawn with GeoGebra] whispers $\color{violet}{w=-\frac 12 - i \frac{\sqrt 7}{2}}.$
Since $w$ verifies $$w^2=\frac{-3}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2}\quad \text{and} \quad w^3=\frac{5}{2} + i\frac{\sqrt 7}{2},$$ it is solution of the given equation.

[image]

**EDIT**
One can proceed similarly with $\color{red}{\overline{a}}$ and $\color{blue}{\overline{b}}$ and conclude that $\color{violet}{\overline{w}}$ is a solution as well.

**Conclusion**
The set of solutions is $\;\{5, -\frac{1}{2} \pm i\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$}.

Comment: I just edited my question with an *answer* that disagrees with yours.  Therefore, if your conclusion is correct, there **must be a flaw in my analysis.**

Comment: You're right! I like your question even more :) I am going to edit my solution. The approach was right, but the conclusion (wrong) was based on the wrong starting point.

Comment: @user2661923 Ordinarily, I would accept your answer, but Christian Blatter's answer is very slick, and I can only accept one answer.  Two questions: 1. **What graphing software did you use?** and 2. **Shouldn't there be 3 elements in your solution set, rather than 2?**  If the analysis in my *answer* is correct then **all 3 candidates** are actually solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends in part on the meaning you give to fractional powers of complex numbers. If you think of $z^{1/n}$ as *any* complex number whose $n$th power is $z$, then you can get $(x+3)^{1/3}$ to equal $(x-1)^{1/2}$ with $x=(-1\pm i\sqrt7)/2$. But if you want $z^{1/n}$ to be a single-valued *function*, then the answer will depend on the *convention* you use for picking the $n$th root.

In particular, most $n$th-root conventions map the upper half plane into the first quadrant (if $n\gt1$). Under any such convention, the argument of $\left({5\over2}+i{\sqrt7\over2} \right)^{1/3}$ is less than $\pi/6$, while the argument of $\left({-3\over2}+i{\sqrt7\over2} \right)^{1/2}$ is greater than $\pi/4$, hence we do not have $(x+3)^{1/3}=(x-1)^{1/2}$ for $x={-1\over2}+i{\sqrt7\over2}$ for those conventions.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Does this mean that in complex analysis, the convention is for the argument of $z^{1/n}$ to be **minimized** in the $[0,2\pi)$ interval?

Comment: @user2661923, there is no such thing as "the" convention for $z^{1/n}$. But yes, that is one way to describe *one* convention.